# Why does $\frac{1}{6e^{2y}}=\frac{1}{2x-8}$ in this context?

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function, inverse

---

This is the context: [image]

I tried substituting $y=3e^{2x}+4$ into $6e^{2y}$but I wasn't able to go any further. Does anyone what exactly is being done in the last step?

Comment: $3e^{2y} + 4 = x \implies 3e^{2y} = x - 4 \implies 6e^{2y} = 2x - 8$.

Comment: @Kaster Thanks, and sorry my stupidity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually want to use a substitution to check your answer, then  if $y=f^{-1}(x)$ and $f(x)=3e^{2x}+4$ then $$y=\dfrac12\log_e\left(\dfrac{x-4}{3}\right)$$

which will give $$\frac{1}{6e^{2y}} = \frac{1}{6e^{\log_e\left(\frac{x-4}{3}\right)}}= \frac{1}{6\left(\frac{x-4}{3}\right)}= \frac{1}{2x-8}$$

but this is not strictly necessary here

Answer (score 1):

From the second line, $x= 3e^{2y} + 4$
$\Rightarrow 3e^{2y} = x-4$
$\Rightarrow 6e^{2y} = 2x-8$.

Answer (score 1):

$3e^{2y} + 4 = x \implies 3e^{2y} = x - 4 \implies 6e^{2y} = 2x - 8
$

Therefore : $\frac{1}{2x - 8
}=\frac{1}{6e^{2y}}$